# Is it a bad habit to move things to tmp?

Tags: directory, mv, tmp

Im not sure what type of issues this could cause (might be none, of course). But when I had a folder a few days ago that could not be deleted even after running:

```
chflags nouchg -R
```

and then

```
sudo rm -rf
```

It would spit out error messages such as `Directory not empty`, etc.

So I renamed it to `/tmp/folder` and when I restarted it was gone. It was the only way I could  do it, I could have probably started in single user or target disk mode to delete it, but it wasn't a big deal. So, is it a bad habit to move things to `/tmp`? Or is there no problem with it at all? I guess theres no problem but I'm just asking to be sure.

Comment: The bad habit is accepting the results of a second thing because the first did not work without understanding why. Though, this question indicates that it is not a habit you have adopted - but I think the title could be changed... *why does moving a dir to `/tmp` delete it but `rm` does not?*

Comment: Are you able to replicate the issue now?

Answer (score 1):

According to TLDP, the `/tmp`  directory...

> contains mostly files that are required temporarily. Many programs use
>   this to create lock files and for temporary storage of data.

It used to be that the system would clear the `/tmp` directory is cleared during boot or shutdown, however, this is no longer guaranteed. Nowadays, many (Linux) systems use the `TMPTIME` variable to govern how often the folder would be cleared.

Moving files/folders to `/tmp` and setting `TMPTIME` to `0` in order to delete them may work, but it is probably bad practice. `/tmp` is not intended to be "Recycle Bin". You should probably investigate why `rm` isn't properly doing the deletion.

As an interesting side note, you could create a directory called `/trash` or something and mount a `tmpfs`. This creates a temporary filesystem in RAM, which will be gone when you shut down the system or if the power is killed.